# How to recover the copy of my meteor site(The local copy has been deleted)

Tags: meteor, telescope

I would like to make changes for my meteor site, but my local copy of the meteor site folder has been deleted, Is there any way to get back the copy?
It would be great help if anyone could suggest a solution.

Here is my meteor site, http://techtrends.meteor.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way to get back the copy? **YES**

**How?**

Contacting the [Meteor Team](http://meteor.com/contact)

I think you can get the client code inspecting the console (hard work) running the `--debug` option (im not sure never do that) but also you wont get the server code since that isn't published to the client.

So Contacting the Meteor Team would be the best option here